# magento Order module not working

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

i am running site in magento 1.9.4 . site is working fine but when i click on orders then it shows errors. i am unable to see orders . i think i get this issue after configuration of payments methods . i use Stripe payment method . if anybody know kindly help me.`The requested Payment Method is not available.

```
Trace:
#0 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(82): Mage::throwException('The requested P...')
#1 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/community/District/Stripe/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid/Renderer/State.php(24): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()
#2 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php(128): District_Stripe_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid_Renderer_State->render(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#3 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml(161): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->getRowField(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#4 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/syzeltdc...')
#5 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#6 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#7 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#11 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#12 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#13 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/syzeltdc...')
#14 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#15 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#16 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#19 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#23 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#24 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/syzeltdc...')
#25 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#26 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#30 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#31 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#32 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#33 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#34 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#35 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#36 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/app/Mage.php(687): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#37 /home2/syzeltdc/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#38 {main}`
```

Comment: debug /app/code/community/District/Stripe/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid/Renderer/State.php this file because issue find in that file

Comment: how to debug or what to change ? any guide

Comment: @Devidas what to change in state.php ? any guide